# problems transfering data from postgres to json

Tags: json, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have tried to export as .json a huge table but I got errors regarding unexpected characters so, I run for all the fields to avoid any conflict:

```
regexp_replace(field_name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_\(\)]','','g')
```

But the results is that everything appears to be empty regexp_replace N as value.

I thought that would resolve the issue. Are there anyway to avoid errors of unexpected characters or NaN, running some query in the table?  Or some process to correctly transform the .json or to transfer the data from postgres to .json.

These are the original errors that after running the command before didn't appear regexp_replace N for all the fields:

- Found unexpected character:

centroid.geojson:13811:

> Found unexpected character
> In `JSON object {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.175797882,51.56044564]},"properties":{"field1":"atribute1","field2":"atribute2","field3":"atribute3","field4":"atribute4","field5":"","atribute5":"","field6":"","field7":"","field8":"","field9":"","date":"27-02-1987","field10":"atribute10","field11":"","atribute11":"","field13":"","field14":"atribute14","field16...`

- Found misspelling of NaN: similar to the other but when working with multipoligons,

> path/to/file.json:398: Found misspelling of NaN
> In
>
> ```
> JSON object {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-0.018498801,51.50229262],[-0.018494037,51.502309446],[-0.018509668,51.502311149],[-0.01851684,51.5023119],[-0.018519242,51.502303037],[-0.01864384,51.502317193],[-0.018640275,51.502329632],[-0.018563854,51.502613229],[-0.018558638,51.502630497],[-0.01842617,51.502615039],[-0.018433776,51.502589179],[-0.018286221,51.502572747],[-0.018048472,51.502546247],[-0.01764496,51.502501208],[-0.017683038,51.502367501],[-0.01768609,51...
> ```

- Found misspelling of Infinity: equal to the previous

Comment: And the original error message would be?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have edited the question adding the exact errors.

Comment: No that is your editing of the error message, we need to see the actual error message as returned by Postgres. Also an example of the offending lines from the JSON file.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, I update the answer I hope that can helps I didn't add it at the beginning because I didn't think they are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the query:

```
UPDATE table SET field = replace(field, '''', '');
```

and then  for NaN and for NULL:

```
UPDATE table SET field= '' WHERE field= 'NaN';
```

and then again the query posted in the question and didn't throw again any of the errors mention before. Seems that all the data are there and correct.